# How to Transform data from the backend with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have react native app. And I am calling a api url. But I don't want to have all the data from the api call. But some specific data. Like name and image.

So I have a service:

```
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://10.14.220.60:8000/animal/categories/main_groups/", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        console.log("RESSPONSE", response);
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const categoryTransform = ({ results = [] }) => {
    const mappedResults = results.map((categoryList) => {
        //categoryList.images = categoryList.images;
        return {
            ...categoryList,
        };
    });

    console.log("MAPPEDRESULT", fetchCategoryData.response());

    return mappedResults;
};
```

and data context:

```
import { Children, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { categoryTransform, fetchCategoryData } from "./category.service";

export const CategoryContext = createContext();

export const CategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const retrieveCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchCategoryData()
                .then(categoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setCategoryList(results);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        }, 200);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveCategories();
    }, []);
    console.log(categoryList);
    return (
        <CategoryContext.Provider
            value={{
                categoryList,
                loading,
                error,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CategoryContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

and component dat injects the data context:

```
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { CategoryContext } from "../../../services/category/category.context";
import { CategoryInfoCard } from "../components/category-info-card.component";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import styled from "styled-components/native";


const SafeArea = styled(SafeAreaView)`
    flex: 1;
    ${StatusBar.currentHeight && `margin-top: ${StatusBar.currentHeight}px`};
`;

const SearchContainer = styled.View`
    padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

const CategoryList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
    contentContainerStyle: {
        padding: 16,
    },
})``;

export const CategoryScreen = () => {
    const { categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <SearchContainer>
                <Searchbar />
            </SearchContainer>
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("ITEMs", item);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <CategoryInfoCard categoryList={item} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

And this is a deault component with hard coded data:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

import { React, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Card } from "react-native-paper";
import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import { Text } from "../../../components/typography/text.component";
import styled from "styled-components/native";


const CategoryCard = styled(Card)`
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

const CategoryGroupCardCover = styled(Card.Cover)`
    padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

export const CategoryInfoCard = ({ categoryList = {} }) => {
    const {
        name = "Zoogdieren",
        images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg",
    } = categoryList;

    return (
        <CategoryCard
            elevation={5}
            style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            }}>
            <Text center variant="h1" style={{ left: 100 }}>
                {name}
            </Text>
            <CategoryGroupCardCover source={{ uri: images }} />
        </CategoryCard>
    );
};
```

So it is about the categoryTransform in the service.

Because when I am calling this function it doesn't work. I get empty array back.

But if I comment the categoryTransform method in the categoryContext. Like:

```
const retrieveCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchCategoryData()
                //.then(categoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setCategoryList(results);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        }, 200);
    };
```

Then it works.

And the api call looks like:

```
ITEMs Object {
  "animals": Array [],
  "category": null,
  "description": "zoogdieren",
  "eaza": "",
  "id": 1,
  "images": "http://10.14.220.60:8000/media/photos/categories/mammal.jpg",
  "legislation": "",
  "name": "zoogdieren",
  "review": "",
}
```

Question: how to fix the categoryTransform method, so that it will filter the specif data: name and images?